# Serilog static logger is SilentLogger when there's an exception in MassTransit AddBus()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, masstransit

We're currently running an ASP.NET Core 3 web app that uses MassTransit. We've chosen Serilog for our logging library and it works great for the most part. We've picked up a small edge case where it cannot log certain errors. In our `Program.cs` (Code snippet below) we initialize the static logger while the service is still starting up and it logs to the console with no problems

If an exception is thrown in the `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup.cs` the service is killed and the exception is printed to the console as expected. However, if an exception is thrown in the MassTransit `AddBus()` method nothing is logged. After a little bit of debugging, we saw that the static logger we set up in `Program.cs` is being replaced with a `SilentLogger` and we believe it could be something internal in MassTransit that's causing this

The MassTransit initialization code can be found below as well

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting up app");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Fatal(e, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }
}
```

```
serviceCollection.AddMassTransit(configurator =>
{
    configurator.AddConsumers(consumerAssembly());

    var queueName = appSettings.QueueName;
    configurator.AddBus(provider =>
    {
        MessageDataDefaults.ExtraTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        MessageDataDefaults.Threshold = 2000;
        MessageDataDefaults.AlwaysWriteToRepository = false;

        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var configHost = appSettings.RabbitMq.Host;
                var configUser = appSettings.RabbitMq.Username;
                var configPassword = appSettings.RabbitMq.Password;

                cfg.Host(new Uri(configHost), h =>
                {
                    h.Username(configUser);
                    h.Password(configPassword);
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName, ec => ec.ConfigureConsumers(provider));
            });
    });

    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusHostedService>();
});
```

Any exception thrown within the `AddBus` method will cause this issue. Here are the versions we're currently using:

- MassTransit 7.1.4
- MassTransit RabbitMq 7.1.4
- Serilog 2.10.0

Perhaps someone here has come across this issue before? Any assistance will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I discovered the same issue and I don't believe the issue has anything to do with the Mass Transit/RabbitMq code.

I am in a .Net core console application.  What we have in common is the `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();` code.  When an uncaught exception occurs within `Run()` and the global `catch (Exception e)` catches it and the `Log.Logger` is now a `SilentLogger`

I put in a work around to reinitialized the Log.Logger in my catch statement.  Unfortunately `SilentLogger` is not public so my check is based on the class name

```
    catch (Exception e) {
         if (Log.Logger.GetType().Name == "SilentLogger")
         {
             InitLogger();
         }
         Log.Fatal(e, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
    }
```

where `InitLogger()` just reinitializes the logger just like in your example:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();
```

This looks like a bug to me where `Log.Logger` is torn down too early for some reason.

Comment: Just ran into this same issue. This is the only thing that works for me. I don't particularly like it though lol

Comment: Thank you for this. This has led me to solution in a completely different case where 'Unleash' .NET client was not using my Serilog logger.

Answer (score 1):

First, I cleaned up your configuration as it has some mixed usage and that's generally frowned upon.

As to the logging issue, MassTransit doesn't know anything about SeriLog, but you can tell MassTransit about Serilog. Use the Serilog.Extensions.Logging package, and be sure to add `ILoggerFactory/ILogger<>` to your service collection using their configuration methods.

```
serviceCollection.AddMassTransit(configurator =>
{
    configurator.AddConsumers(consumerAssembly());

    configurator.UsingRabbitMq((context,cfg) =>
    {
        // these can actually go anywhere before the bus is created
        MessageDataDefaults.ExtraTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        MessageDataDefaults.Threshold = 2000;
        MessageDataDefaults.AlwaysWriteToRepository = false;

        var configHost = appSettings.RabbitMq.Host;
        var configUser = appSettings.RabbitMq.Username;
        var configPassword = appSettings.RabbitMq.Password;

        cfg.Host(new Uri(configHost), h =>
        {
            h.Username(configUser);
            h.Password(configPassword);
        });

        var queueName = appSettings.QueueName;
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName, ec => ec.ConfigureConsumers(context));
    });
});
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusHostedService>();
```

Possible syntax to add Serilog to the container:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(_ => new SerilogLoggerFactory());
services.TryAddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated the MassTransit setup using the snippet you provided above, I also added Serilog to the DI container but I'm still running into the same issue. Just in this case any exception now thrown in 'UsingRabbitMq()' isn't caught in 'Program.cs', it just prints "Starting up app" and then dies

Comment: What exception is thrown, that isn't caught?

Comment: So we found this when the 'RabbitMq' object was null and a NullReferenceException was thrown. After that, we tried with our own custom exception and saw the same thing happen

Comment: It's probably being thrown in your BusHostedService, or the factory of it, which tries to resolve the bus from the container, which of course throws an exception because the factory method for the object threw an exception.

Comment: We'll add some catch statements there and see if we're able to catch the exception, but for interest's sake, how would that stop the exception from being logged?